# XmlHttpRequest not working, saying module not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a application where I am using AWS Cognito for Authentication, I have created

- Login Page in HTML
- On same page inside  I got all temporary credentials
- Using these credentials I am trying to create a URL to AWS Management Console but I am facing some issues

  ```
  var signin_url = "https://signin.aws.amazon.com/federation";

  var sessionTokenJSON = {
                  sessionId : 'someValue',
                  sessionKey : 'someValue',
                  sessionToken : 'someValue'
              };


   var sessionTokenString = JSON.stringify(sessionTokenJSON);
              var encodedSessionToken = encodeURIComponent(sessionTokenString);

     var signInURL = signin_url+"?Action=getSigninToken&Session="+encodedSessionToken;
  console.log(signInURL);
  ```

Till here it is working fine. Next is I have to get SignInToken by making a Get Request from above URL, who response will be like this

```
 {
   "SigninToken":"VsPfcblaC....."
    }
```

I am not able to make this Get Call, What I am trying is

```
      var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open( "GET", signInURL, false );
                xmlHttp.send( null );
                var result =  xmlHttp.responseText;
                result = JSON.parse(result);
```

It say XMLHttpRequest module not defined, I have seen many articles but it didnt work for me, Can anyone suggest how to proceed further, I am not running anything on server, I have hosted this application on S3 Bucket.

Comment: Do i need to install node JS server?

Comment: I am running in browser only, No Node JS environment is involved, I have node JS script also which is working fine, But I am getting Credentials in Pure JS and URL Generator in Node is getting difficult to integrate both scripts

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you're running the Request on the Server. The XMLHttpRequest is not available in Node by default, but in Browsers it is.

You can try:

1. Using the Node Built-in library: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

---

2. Or: Add it to the server

```sh
npm install xmlhttprequest
```

```js
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
```

---

3. Or: Install a third-party tool like RxJS or Axios

Comment: server is involved no where and node js also no involved